# Python - Copying lists in a loop

Tags: python

I'm kinda new to python... So I've been strugling with a problem for a while and after doing a huge research I did not find solution so I decided to ask here :).

So the code that is explaining my problem:

```
test = []
solutions = []

i = 0
while i < 100:
    for i in range(0, 64):
        pos = random.randrange(0, 64)
        test.append(pos)
    solutions.append(test)
    test.clear()
    i += 1
```

So I want to add a copy of a table to another table everytime the loop goes and then clean the table named test. The problem is I don't know how to create a copy of list each time the loop goes. So I'm getting list of empty lists :(

I tried with copy.copy or copy.deepcopy but that didn't work.

That is my first question here so sorry for any "errors" also I'm not native english speaker but I hope you will be able to understand me.

Comment: Not sure what you want to do here, but the `while` loop will never end. Even adding `i += 1` will not be enough (though it is necessary). You have to use 2 distincts names for the `i` in the `while` loop and the on in the `for` loop, or use `for _ in range(0, 64)` for instance

Comment: Yea I'll edit my question

Answer (score 0):

You can append duplicates by calling the list constructor

```
solutions.append(list(test))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want clean simply dont use test.clear()

use:

```
test = []
```

you should remove the test.clear(), and change <100 of while because is infinite

```
import random
test = []
solutions = []

i = 0
while i < 100:
    for i in range(0, 64):
        pos = random.randrange(0, 64)
        test.append(pos)
    solutions.append(test)
```

Comment: This will not solve the problem, given it will lead solutions to be full of empty lists…

Comment: @Zaphod: That depends on where you put it.  If you put it before the `for i in range(64):` loop and remove `test.clear()`, it should work fine.

Comment: ahh, i cant understant what do you need exactly

Answer (score 0):

You can do copy the list like:

```
solutions.append(test[:])
```

And to empty it, since there is no empty method, you can just reassign it to a new empty list:

```
test = []
```

Like Zaphod mentioned, your `while` loop never finished, since you were never updating the value of i, plus is was being assigned in the inner for loop anyway. Why not use two nested `for` loops?  (the underscore is just a var placeholder signifying the value is not used)

```
import random

test = []
solutions = []

for _ in range(0, 100):
    for i in range(0, 64):
        pos = random.randrange(0, 64)
        test.append(pos)
    solutions.append(test[:])
    test = []
print solutions
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks!

@Edit I wanted list of "new lists" not list of "the same list"

So yea you answer is what I was looking for. Thanks again : )